# wordpress in GAE wp-admin area css and js not loading

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I recently add wordpress to Google App Engine

Everything is working fine in the local PHP SDK

I used git it deploy the site to GAE, problem is in the live site admin area (wp-admin) one css and one js is not loading so I'm getting a display like this 
[image]

I checked the missing resource they are

```
myappid.appspot../wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load=admin-bar,wp-admin,buttons,wp-auth-check&ver=3.6.1
```

and

```
myappid.appspot.../wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,json2&ver=3.6.1
```

These resources are loading fine in the local GAE PHP SDK. I'm using the same app.yaml that given in the google wordpress tutorial

I spend 2 days finding a solution for this Please help me out :)

Comment: ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

This is my app.yaml file

```
application: entersys-wordpress
version: wp
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug if you use git to deploy not correctly pushing the static content.

I would try using the appcfg.py method to push your app to check (Follow Step 8 [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress)).

Comment: I tried the same directory adding to another project using the appcfg.py and even the from the php sdk. still no difference :'(

Comment: either you have an error in the app.yaml file or you project is missing the css file. enable debug in WP and see if it logs which file it cannot find.

Comment: well my local is working perfectly
this is the app.yaml file see the answer